# Would two 70 pint dehumidifiers work as well as one 140 pint unit?

Tags: humidity, dehumidifier

If so why are dehumidifiers above 70 pt so much more expensive? pros cons? Having two 70 pt in same room vs 1 140 pt?

Comment: 1. yes ... 2. see #1 ... 3. unclear what is being asked ... 4. also unclear

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Unfortunately, without studying the supply chain and consumer demand, we can't answer your first question. And, the second question is probably convenience; do you  want two loud boxes in your room, rather than one?

Comment: I would anticipate two dehumidifiers to be more effective than one with an equal capacity. Why? Surface areas would be the primary reason. Not to mention they can be placed in two affected areas vs. only one. However, now you are spending more energy to drive two compressors instead of one. Bigger is sometimes better, but when you use more metal, more coolant, more engineering to fit more in a smallish package, prices go up. Supply and demand would also play a role. Ultimately the manufacturer is going to push the product they can sell more of, more often.

Comment: @DanielGriscom I get that, I'm just wondering as an end user is there any advantage such as less heat output or units above 70 pt are simply overpriced because of low demand?

Comment: @UnhandledExcepSean that would make more sense...

Comment: I'd suggest breaking this into multiple questions; as it is, it's hard to answer, and removing the question about why 140 pint humidifiers are more expensive.

Comment: Do you have any interest in air conditioning the space?  An air conditioner is simply a dehumidifier with different ducting on the hot side (the side that does not matter to water removal).

Answer (score 2):

### You crossed the line into industrial

I immediately noticed that a search for 70 pint dehumidifiers yielded the usual consumer tier listings... Target Walmart CostCo Home Depot etc. Different deal for 140pt. It gave my local heating /cooling contractor, damage response companies, and industrial suppliers.

So you have made a qualitative leap. From Yukon to Humvee.  This also affects what the customers are looking for.

- The consumer product wins when you put it in your cart, what happens afterward hardly matters.   The industrial product wins then it has lowest total cost of ownership.
- the consumer unit is built no tougher than it needs to be to be parked in a corner for five years. The industrial unit is designed to be dragged around to job sites every day.
- the consumer unit is absolutely designed to work on lowest common denominator mains power,  probably 120V at 12A max.  The industrial unit,  all bets are off. It's assumed a lot of equipment will be in use at that job site,  and someone will be managing electrical loads.
- it is also assumed that very dirty power will be on that job site, possibly from a generator,  and so the unit will be built for that, and also will have no compunction about creating dirt on the lines.
- as part of the "total life cycle" mentality, the industrial unit will be repairable for considerably less than the cost of a new one. This maintenance may be required.   The consumer unit, into the trash it goes.
- industrial units are often deployed with pusher fans to circulate humid air to the unit, so one unit can service a large area. It is sized for that. A consumer is unlikely to do such engineering or desire it.
- the consumer unit factors for consumer sensibilities in style, efficiency and noise.   The industrial unit, nope.

These factors, rather than cost, should guide your decision.

Nothing wrong with arrays of cheap expendables;  Google won the search business using numerous cheap beige box PCs while competitors used top tier DEC and Sun systems. Google was forced to learn to adapt to constant hardware failure.

Comment: The consumer product will be designed for a maximum noise level based on consumer perceptions. The industrial product will be designed for maximum noise level based on OSHA requirements - and not one decibel less!

Comment: As far as Google adapting to HW failure - yes, they did. In the end they came out way ahead. I suspect (from casual reading, not real research) that Google learning to adapt to 'x' % hard drive, motherboard, etc. failures where 'x' > 'y' of top tier machines, paid off when they scaled to thousands of machines per data center where **any** brand will have some number of failures and Google is able to manage the problem well. A lot of hosting companies (except the one I mainly work with - partly due to their efficiency in handling the inevitable occasional failures) still haven't figured it out.

Answer (score 1):

I would opt for 2 units for several reasons, but the reasons that the 140 pt dehumidifiers are more expensive is they usually require wheels and handles some have pumps that the smaller units don’t have.

Why would I opt for multiple units, a room is a fixed area de humidifiers can only draw the moisture out of the air if the air is available, for example, having a large bonus room down the hall from our kitchen and dining area, if we only use a dehumidifier in the large bonus room the dining area will be very humid and the bedrooms even further away will be worse at night. What we had was 2 smaller units 1 in the bonus room and one in the dining room since it had more space and was closer to the bedrooms, this worked quite well (a whole house system was not an option because the bonus room was on a different system than the rest of the home). 
So for more effective moisture removal having smaller units at multiple locations is better. The cost is reduced because the lighter units are easier to carry or move around, as far as noise I find the fans that move the air are the majority of the noise on the units I have had with out air movement the units won’t do much good so the larger units have much larger fans trying to move the air.  So depending on the layout of your home I would suggest smaller units, even with open layout having smaller units at opposite ends of the area will function better , be quieter and less expensive, the con for 2 units now you have 2 water buckets to empty.

Answer (score 0):

I would opt for the 2 dehumidifiers over the 1 just due to the noise that the single large unit produces. My neighbor has one of those large dehumidifiers which is rated near the 140 pint/day you asked about and it is extremely noisy, was very expensive, and takes up a lot of floor space. While the water removing capacity would be about the same, those large units are usually very expensive to buy or replace. "My 2 cents"